# Regex Replacing issue understanding

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to program a replacement logic for invalid phone numbers, which I provide with a Map 
I read through a few Regex expressions threads, but I don't know if this actually is possible.

Example:

Input phone number: +410712345678

regex I'm trying to use:

```
 "^\\+(?:[0-9] ?){6,14}[0-9]$"
```

number after regex and filtering should be: +41712345678. So actually removing the first Instance of 0.

Second example:

input phone number: +41(071)2345678

regex I'm trying to use:

```
"^\\+(?:[0-9] ?)\\({0,3}\\){3,11}[0-9]$"
```

number after regex and filtering should be: +41712345678. So actually removing the First Instance of 0 and also the braces.

I'm trying to user some kind of pattern to automatically remove those invalid pieces from those phone numbers. The numbers need to be formatted that way to work with my VOIP application.

Is there any way to create a filter pattern like that with regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you should only apply that rule for Switzerland phone number, i.e. for `+41` numbers, because simply removing the first `0` from any international number is wrong.

So, `ph = ph.replaceFirst("^(\\+41)\\(?0?([0-9]{2})\\)?", "$1$2")`.

See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kV3vW4/1) for how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer.

I applied the Regex to my TestImport with the following code:

```
 //...

log.debug("Applying Regex :" + SearchString + " with Replace: " + ReplaceString);   

log.debug("Applying Regex for Number:" + Person.get(EPerson.Rufnummer));
Person.put(EPerson.Rufnummer, Person.get(EPerson.Rufnummer).replaceFirst(SearchString, ReplaceString));
log.debug("New Number is:" +Person.get(EPerson.Rufnummer));

log.debug("Applying Regex for Number:" + Person.get(EPerson.RufnummerMobil));
Person.put(EPerson.RufnummerMobil, Person.get(EPerson.RufnummerMobil).replaceFirst(SearchString, ReplaceString));
log.debug("New Number is:" +Person.get(EPerson.RufnummerMobil));
    //...
```

DEBUG [AddressbookFactory] Applying Numberfilter to: {Vorname=Testinator, Nachname=Test, Rufnummer=+410717271818, RufnummerMobil=, RufnummerPrivat=+41(071)7271818, Fax=, Strasse=, PLZ=, Stadt=, Bundesland=, Email=, Firma=, URL=}

DEBUG [AddressbookFactory] Regex Detected

DEBUG [AddressbookFactory] Applying Regex :^(+41)(?0?([0-9]{2}))? with Replace: $1$2

DEBUG [AddressbookFactory] Applying Regex for Number:+410717271818

DEBUG [AddressbookFactory] New Number is: +41717271818

DEBUG [AddressbookFactory] Applying Regex for Number:+41(071)7271818

DEBUG [AddressbookFactory] New Number is: +41717271818 
...

And it worked!

Thank you so much for your Quick Response!

I marked your answer as useful, but trough my "newbie" Reputation it does not indicate it.

This Question is resolved.

Sincerly Fabian95qw